# can't serialize object type System.Double[,]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello again i finally finish my web service and client and it works fine from the client side how ever when i try to acces de server from my web browser i receive the error can't serialize object type System.Double[,] No support multidimensional arrays. I think it's due to my webmethod return a multidimensional array, how ever i need to return this array, con someone help try to solve this error or how to work aroudn it
note: i am usign C#, asp.net. IIS, write in the NotePad, not using visual studio

Comment: Why are you punishing yourself by writing in notepad? VSExpress should ease your development experience considerably!

Comment: @spender this is because my investigation has to show how to do it all by your self, step by step, and not depend on softwares like VS :D yes i know its more work and stupid but that's how they order my how to do my work  :´(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reencode your data as `double[][]`

Here's a method do do it:

```
public static T[][] ConvertToJaggedArray<T>(T [,] multiArray)
{
  int numOfColumns=multiArray.GetLength(0);
  int numOfRows=multiArray.GetLength(1);
  T[][] jaggedArray = new T[numOfColumns][];

  for (int c = 0; c < numOfColumns; c++)
  {
      jaggedArray[c] = new T[numOfRows];
      for (int r = 0; r < numOfRows; r++)
      {
          jaggedArray[c][r] = multiArray[c, r];
      }
  }

  return jaggedArray;
}
```

Comment: nice code, but one question it may be very dumb from me but how do i call the method from my main? my previus method have the something like this: public double[,] Parametros(int a, int b, string d,DateTime startTime, out double [,]array1, out string time1, out DateTime start_F) where a and b are the lenght of the array the return was an multidimensional array whit many double values

Comment: never mind based on your code i have develop my own thank you for the answer